# using command line arguments in loop shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use command line arguments for arithmetic but cant seem to find any documentation explaining how to do this. As an example if I use:

```
for i in {$1..$2}
do 
echo $i 
done
```

and call

```
test.sh 1 20
```

the following output is produced:

```
{1..20}
```

instead of

```
1
2
3
.. 
20
```

Comment: This is bash, so a c-style for loop `for ((i = $1; i <= $2; i++)); do ...` is also an option. For POSIX shell, you can always use `i = $1; while [ "$i" -le "$2" ]; do ... ((i++)); done` as another option.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this properly without *the evil eval()* with *brace expansion* in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

You can use `seq` instead :

```
for i in $(seq $1 $2); do
```

Comment: answering a well-known duplicate :/

Comment: I would definitely suggest a comment alone without DV is sufficient reminder... we don't need to be nickle and diming each other here.

Comment: @David How could I know you're talking to me if you don't @ me ? :D

Comment: Hmmm... process of elimination? `:)` I do think among  those that have been here a while, a friendly reminder instead of a ding is probably good practice. I know I've been guilty of answering a duplicate before -- especially when searching and "Related" don't disclose them immediately. In fact, a check of the entire *Related* list to the right doesn't disclose anything related (very flawed algorithm), but like you, I know one should exist.

Comment: Okay, next time I won't dv

Comment: What does DV means ?

Answer (score 0):

The following will also work:

```
declare -a ary='({'$1..$2'})'
for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Note that `declare` is as **harmful** as `eval`.
You need to check and sanitize the arguments before use.

Comment: Huh? I've never hear `declare` being considered harmful. For 30 years I've been under the impression it was helpful. (but certainly never as you use it above...) `eval` is only one character away from `evil`, but `declare` is innocent of any crime...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the comment. We can invoke the script above with `test.sh 1 '$(rm file)'` then it removes `file` if exists. We can inject any command as an argument. That is my concern.

Comment: Those are valid concerns. I can honestly say I've never seen `declare` abused this way before `:)`,

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for your attention.There will be no end if we worry and need to find a practical solution depending on the usage and requirements. BR.